# Find nearest pair (matching lon and lat) - need date match condition

Tags: python, pandas, distance, latitude-longitude

First time poster struggling with some code. I have leveraged (https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/finding-nearest-pair-of-latitude-and-longitude-match-using-python-ce50d62af546) to match an individuals location to businesses within a region, based off longitude and latitude.

However, I am struggling to make a date condition within the code. I need the dates to match as it will give me the closest business to a person but it may have closed down 10 years prior. What I really need is for it  provide me with the closest location for a person to a business on a given date. **Both datasets have: Date, name, lon, lat.**

## Copy of code

```
# 1 Import and load
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
def dist(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):

# 2 Convert decimal degrees to radians 
lat1, long1, lat2, long2 = map(radians, [lat1, long1, lat2, long2])

# 3 Haversine formula 
dlon = long2 - long1 
dlat = lat2 - lat1 
a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
# Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
km = 6371* c
return km

# 4 The above calculate the distance to all businesses. Using idxmin you can find the closest business name using:
 def find_nearest(lat, long):
    distances = hotels.apply(
        lambda row: dist(lat, long, row['lat'], row['lon']), 
        axis=1)
    return hotels.loc[distances.idxmin(), 'name']

# 5 Once we have the closest businesses, now just append the results backs to the Original insider's data using:
members['name'] = members.apply(
lambda row: find_nearest(row['lat'], row['lon']),axis=1)

# 6 Check and merge
members.head()
members1 = pd.merge(members,hotels[['name','lat','lon']],on=[['name','date']], how='left')

# 7 Rename the new columns  
members=members.rename(columns ={'lat_x':'m_lat','lon_x':'m_lon','lat_y':'h_lat','lon_y':'h_lon'})
    members.head()

# 8 Defining haversine dist and calling it
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
   def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
# convert decimal degrees to radians 
lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
# haversine formula 
dlon = lon2 - lon1 
dlat = lat2 - lat1 
a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
# Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
km = 6371* c
return km

# 9 Creating a new column to generate the output by passing lat long information to Haversine Equation
  members['distance'] = [haversine(members.m_lon[i],members.m_lat[i],members.h_lon[i],members.h_lat[i]) for i in 
    range(len(members))]
    members['distance'] = members['distance'].round(decimals=3)

# 10 Printing the data table to check & Merge
members.head()
members1 = pd.merge(members,hotels[['name','lat','lon']],on=[['name','date']], how='left')

# 11 Rename the new columns and merge 
members1=members1.rename(columns = {'lat_x':'m_lat','lon_x':'m_lon','lat_y':'h_lat','lon_y':'h_lon'})
members1.head()

#12  Calculate the great circle distance between two points on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
       def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    # Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
    km = 6371* c
    return km

# 13 Creating a new column to generate the output by passing lat long information to Haversine Equation
members1['distance'] = [haversine(members1.m_lon[i],members1.m_lat[i],members1.h_lon[i],members1.h_lat[i]) for i in range(len(members1))]
members1['distance'] = members1['distance'].round(decimals=3)
  
# 14 Read & Write
members1.head()
members1.to_csv(r'D:\Coding Data\members.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Maybe you should consider post your question in https://gis.stackexchange.com/ instead.